# Double definite integral: $\int \limits_0^3 \int \limits_0^4\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int \limits_0^3 \int \limits_0^4\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$
 Please answer this question step by step. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try substitution.

Comment: sorry I havent got it.. Please elaborate your answer..

Answer (score 3):

You may use polar coordinates with this limit:

$$\left(\int_0^{\sin^{-1}(4/3)}\int_0^{3\sec(\theta)}+\int_{\sin^{-1}(4/3)}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{4\csc(\theta)}\right)f(r,\theta)rdrd\theta$$
wherein

$$f(r,\theta)=\sqrt{25-r^2}$$

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I think given question is f(x,y) it can be converted into cylindrical coordinates not into polar coordinates.

Comment: @user118555 no, cylindrical coordinates are for triple integrals with $x,y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Use polar coordinates:

$$x=r \cos t$$ $$y=r \sin t$$

and $$dydx=r\ drdt$$

where $r$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: That's not so convenient for the domain of integration here, which is a rectangle (with different sides).

Comment: My mistake there. I did not see the lower and upper limits properly.

Comment: The method that Ross had suggested is really difficult. I tried solving the integral by hand and it's honestly not easy. I would bend towards @B.S. 's method.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^3\int_0^4\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}~dy~dx$

$=\int_0^3\left[\dfrac{y\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}}{2}+\dfrac{25-x^2}{2}\sin^{-1}\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\right]_0^4~dx$ (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_irrational_functions)

$=\int_0^32\sqrt{9-x^2}~dx+\int_0^3\dfrac{25-x^2}{2}\sin^{-1}\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}dx$

Can you take it from here?